# Python - None value is being returned from a count

Tags: python, count, return

I'm trying to count the max number of spaces there are in a sentence with the following code:

```
def spaces(sentences):
  textList = sentences.split('. ')
  whiteList = [whitespaces.count(' ') for whitespaces in textList]
  x = max(whiteList)
  print(x)
```

However, while it is returning the number of whitespaces there are, this is also returning a `None` on a second line. How come this is the case?

Comment: You function doesn't `return` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return a value from your function and then print the result of it

```
def spaces(sentences):
  textList = sentences.split('. ')
  whiteList = [whitespaces.count(' ') for whitespaces in textList]

  return max(whiteList)

print(spaces(sentences))
```

Answer (score 0):

You print the result, but you don't return it. You need to add `return x` at the end of your code.

You can check [this page](https://foo.cs.ucsb.edu/8wiki/index.php/Python:_Print_vs_Return), which explains the difference between `print` and `return` in Python.